# How to change route inside the function "autocomplete.addListener()" ? AngularJs Google Maps API

Tags: angularjs, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-autocomplete

I want On selecting one suggestion the route to be changed to `'/blood_test'` but its not happening, only getting the console.log properly

but on putting the `$location.path('/blood_test');` outside the function the route is changing

```
 $location.path('/blood_test');
autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', function() {
          console.log('yoyoyoyo');
          $location.path('/blood_test');
       });

 autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', function() {
          console.log('yoyoyoyo');
          $location.path('/blood_test');
       });
```

I expect the change of route to '/blood_test' but its staying in the same route.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`place_changed` event is triggered outside of the angular context, you have to replace

```
$location.path(url);
```

with

```
$scope.$apply(function() {
    $location.path(url);
});
```

[Here is a demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/JWpZ7wEcgobMeLY6LV9I?p=preview)